# C function delimiates strings using a single character array

Tags: c, strings

I am a complete noob to C and I've shied away from using such a powerful language due to it's large learning curve and other complicated mechanisms. For my first *minor* project I plan to create a small HTTP client that requests for a webpage. Before I start, I need to create a function that can correctly parse a URL using the URI scheme. I devised this function to help me separate `http` from a host name like `www.google.com` by recognizing `://`. Space and clock efficiency is are priorities of mine. I'm looking for any tips that would help someone who is new to C.

```
int delimiateString(const char *string, const char *delimiator) {
    const char *buffer;
    int x, len = strlen(delimiator);
    for (buffer = string; *buffer != '\0'; buffer++) {
        if (*delimiator == *buffer) {
            for (x = 1; x <= len; x++) {
                if (*(delimiator+x) == *(buffer+x)) {
                    if (x+1 == len) {
                        return (buffer - string);
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return strlen(string);
}
```

Comment: strchr will search through the entire delimiator. That's not what you want. You want to check only the first letter. So you should replace `if(strchr(delimiator, *buffer) != NULL` with `if(*delimiator == *buffer)`. Or just just strcmp instead. But why do you use C for an HTTP client? That would be a lot easier in many other languages.

Comment: Okay, will do. I'm using C just to learn the language.

Comment: Can you show an example usage of this function? Would `://` be the delimiter or would `/`? What does this function return? The usage seems a bit awkward to me, and I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Since I'm working on the ground up, I really don't have any full code but I only have a rough plan. `char *text = "http://mhjj:popi@192.168.0.2:8888/servlet/rece/"; int i = delimiateString(text, "://");` is the intended use currently and it would help me get the appropriate length (from the beginning of the string) to allocate the protocol string "http" and to help me extract the remaining portion of text that would need to be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems to do this:

- Find the first occurrence of "delimiator" (*delimiter?*) in some string. For example find the first occurrence of `://` in `http://example.com`.
- If found, return the position where it was found
- If not found, return the length of the input string

To find if a string is part of another string, you can use the `strstr` function.
This is equivalent to your code but simpler:

```
int delimiateString(const char *string, const char *delimiator) {
    char * found = strstr(string, delimiator);
    return found != NULL ? found - string : strlen(string);
}
```

For the record,
your original code can be simplified,
by eliminating an `if` around the inner `for` loop,
and rearranging the nested `if`s at the deepest level:

```
for (buffer = string; *buffer != '\0'; buffer++) {
    for (x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        if (*(delimiator+x) != *(buffer+x)) {
            break;
        }
        if (x+1 == len) {
            return buffer - string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I'm foolish to have not found strstr before. At least the time spent making that function was not to waste for I need the practice.